# How to perform operations with Imagebuttons widget in android

Tags: android, android-widget, imagebutton

I have created a simple application in which I have 3 Imagebuttons in an activity. These buttons are performing some operations. Further I want to create a widget on home screen having the 3 Buttons which is performing same operations like the imageButtons in the activity.
I have read many tutorials but cannot find a suitable one.

The widget looks like this:

[image]

**XML code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:background="@drawable/my_shape"
  android:layout_gravity="center"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">

  <ImageButton
   android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
   android:layout_width="52dip"
   android:layout_height="50dip"
   android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center"
   android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

  <ImageButton
   android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
   android:layout_width="52dip"
   android:layout_height="50dip"
   android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center"
   android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

  <ImageButton
   android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
   android:layout_width="52dip"
   android:layout_height="50dip"
   android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center"
   android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

  <ImageButton
   android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
   android:layout_width="52dip"
   android:layout_height="50dip"
   android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center"
   android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

   </LinearLayout>
```

**Widget_info.xml in res/xml:**

```
 <appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:minWidth="146dip"
 android:minHeight="72dip"
 android:updatePeriodMillis="0"
 android:initialLayout="@layout/widget_layout"/>
```

I also have widgets details in manifestfile.

I have not included activity code here. In the activity there are 3 imageButton onclick methods and I want the widgets buttons (3 button) to do exactly these operations.

Please can anyone guide me on this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with the help of [`setOnClickPendingIntent`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews.html#setOnClickPendingIntent%28int,android.app.PendingIntent%29).

```
public class Widget extends AppWidgetProvider {

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
            int[] appWidgetIds) {
        super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
        final int N = appWidgetIds.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];
                    // For first image
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, SplashActivity.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
                    intent, 0);
            RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
                    R.layout.appwidget);
            views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.imageButton1, pendingIntent);
                    //For second Image
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, HomeActivity.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent1 = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
                    intent1, 0);
            views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.imageButton2, pendingIntent1);

                    // like wise you can add your consecutive classes.

            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
        }

    }
}
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: can u be more clear..how onclick on widget button will act same as onclick of button in actvity

Comment: Kindly Note `views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.imageButton1, pendingIntent1);`. In this line you have to define which `pendingIntent` have to get invoked by clicking corresponding `imageButton`.

Comment: sorry ,help me out with my code,activity code is above,please check

Answer (score 0):

In my HomeActivity :

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    imgbtn1=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageCallButton1);
    imgbtn2=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageFBButton1);
    imgbtn3=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageSmsButton1);

    imgbtn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "U clicked on Call Button", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
  imgbtn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "U clicked on FB Button", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
   imgbtn3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "U clicked on SMS Button", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
    }
```

**In my MyWidgetProvider activity:**

```
public class MyWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {

@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
        int[] appWidgetIds) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       //what should be added here
    super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
  }
         }
```

Comment: No man. `AppWidgetProvider` is used for launch an activity from homescreen with the help of widgets (Some Views. In your case image button.). So you have to define which activity have to invoked by clikcing your widgets in your `MyWidgetProvider`. Your activity will work without any intruption. You have to change your `MyWidgetProvider` class only(like my answer). Or else just google about "difference between widget and activity`.

Comment: Also what if i don't want to call entire activity,i just want to perform a button onclick event which is inside an activity through this button widget

Comment: For this purpose take a look an [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidWidgets/article.html). Perfect tutorial.